# Change some file names (prefix to postfix)

Tags: files, rename, filenames, suse

I have a directory containing thousands of files with names
`t_00xx_000xxx.png` and `00xx_000xxx.png`. I want to change the names of the files which starts with `t_`, like `t_00xx_000xxx.png` to `00xx_000xxx_t.png`

So take the prefix and put it as a postfix for some of the files. Can this be done in only one command?

I am running on SUSE SLES12 SP2.

Comment: OP has no `prename` and no admin rights to install anything.

Comment: are all files in one folder?

Comment: I have something in mind, correct me if I am wrong.
If there is a way to loop on all files `t_*`, I can use `mv` command, something like `mv t_* *_t` where * is a single filename within the loop

Comment: @RoVo yes they are

Comment: @Mostafa `mv` doesn't work like that. It's going to take `*_t` as a directory name then give you an error when it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will work if we assume everything up to the first underscore to be the prefix.

```
for f in *.png; do
    new=$(echo "$f" | sed -r 's/^([^_]*)_(.*)\.(.*)$/\2_\1.\3/');
    echo "Renaming: $f => $new";
    #mv $f $new
done
```

Remove the `#` in front of `mv` if you're happy with the output.

---

With `prename` it would be a little easier:

```
prename -n 's/^([^_]*)_(.*)\.(.*)$/$2_$1.$3/'
```

---

If `t_` is always the prefix, change to this pattern:

```
for f in t_*.png; do
    new=$(echo "$f" | sed -r 's/^t_(.*)\.(.*)$/\1_t.\2/');
    echo "Renaming: $f => $new";
    #mv $f $new
done
```

Comment: `
Renaming: 0020_000834.png => 000834_0020.png
Renaming: 0020_000835.png => 000835_0020.png
Renaming: 0020_000836.png => 000836_0020.png
Renaming: 00xx_000xxx_t.png => 000xxx_t_00xx.png
Renaming: t_0000_000000.png => 0000_000000_t.png
Renaming: t_0000_000001.png => 0000_000001_t.png
Renaming: t_0000_000002.png => 0000_000002_t.png
`

Comment: so for the t files it worked, for the others not

Comment: oh yes it worked well when my assumptions would have been correct... it seems they were wrong. Is always just `t_` the prefix ?

Comment: the folder contains files with `t_` and files with not, so I need to perform this operation on only files with `t_` ... I would say that I replace this for `f in *.png; do` with for `f in t_*.png; do`, right ? or what do you think ?

Comment: that would work, yes!

Comment: so which answer shall I use, I don't get your second solution, if t_ is always the prefix, this means that it will search only for files which has t_ ?

Comment: no, it will just match files with `t_`, and with the others it won't do anything, because you have no match. But I edited that version to include `for f in t_*.png` ;-)

Comment: using your second solution, I received this error
`Renaming: t_0005_000230.png =>
sed: -e expression #1, char 25: invalid reference \3 on ``s' command's RHS`

Comment: I already updated it... reload and try again

Comment: I tried your first solution again with replacing `f in *.png; do` by `for f in t_*.png; do`, and it worked

Answer (score 7):

Given the filename pattern `t_00xx_000xxx.png` where the x's could be any single character, the following loop uses the `?` globbing character substitute for the variable characters. The loop picks up only files that start with `t_` and that end in `.png`. It uses parameter expansion to strip off the leading `t_`, then extracts the desired substring in order to move the `_t` into the desired position.

```
for f in t_00??_000???.png
do
  echo mv -- "$f" "${f:2:11}_t.png"
done
```

For some made-up filenames, the sample output is:

```
mv t_0011_000111.png 0011_000111_t.png
mv t_0012_000345.png 0012_000345_t.png
mv t_00xx_000xxx.png 00xx_000xxx_t.png
```

Remove the `echo` portion if the results look correct.

Answer (score 5):

In `sh` syntax:

```
for f in t_*.*; do
  dest=${f#t_}
  dest=${dest%.*}_t.${dest##*.}
  echo mv -i -- "$f" "$dest"
done
```

Answer (score 5):

If [SuSE SLES12 has mcp/mmv command](https://www.unix.com/man-page/suse/1/mcp/) in its repository, then it would be simple use of `mmv`:

```
mmv 't_*.png' '#1_t.png'
```

Or, if the number of characters and specific numbers was issue, you could be more specific like:

```
mmv 't_00??_000???.png' '00#1#2_000#3#4#5_t.png'
```

First argument to *mmv* is source, with standard wildcards `*` and `?`. The second argument is destination, in which *#1* is replaced with content which first wildcard matched, *#2* with content which second wildcard matched etc.

Example:

```
% ls -1
t_0011_000037.png
t_0011_000038.png
t_0011_000039.png
t_0022_000001.png
t_0022_000002.png

% mmv 't_*.png' '#1_t.png'

% ls -1
0011_000037_t.png
0011_000038_t.png
0011_000039_t.png
0022_000001_t.png
0022_000002_t.png
```